# Анимация при удалении контрола из контейнера

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть какой то контейнер с автоматическим позиционированием элементов. Например, `StackPanel` или `WrapPanel`. Коллекция заполнена привязкой данных. Допустим, я удаляю из контейнера один из элементов. Как сделать плавное перемещение на новые места остальных элементов?

Comment: Вероятнее всего вам придется писать свой контрол, на основе StackPanel или WrapPanel, и к нему уже цеплять такую анимацию.

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov, зачем? Для этого что, придется какие то свойства определять новые? Я думал это делается просто стилем

Comment: с помощь Interactions из Blend вы можете сделать все что вам заблагорассудится, просто зайдите в Expression Blend, выберите контрол который вам нужен и киньте на него Interaction.Triggers с экшеном InvokeCommandAction. также  в него можно поместить какие либо экшены из prism, нужно только его подключить. Это даст вам безграничные возможности в плане GUI! Попробуйте это легко!

Comment: Еще вопрос вы заполнили StackPanel привязкой данных? По-моему у него нет свойства ItemsSource...

Comment: @cvvvlad, любой контейнер можно заполнить биндингом. Надо только знать как :) В случае со стак панелью, надо просто использовать ItemsControl и стак панель в качестве панели. А есть иные способы кроме Blend'a? Я как то не привык ничего никуда кидать через ГУИ, весь интерфейс пишу ручками

Comment: @iRumba Blend просто сможет вам подключить свои библиотеки автоматом и там вы уже сможете использовать xml-namespace "interactivity". По умолчанию без помощи Мелкософотовких дополнений типа prism и blend wpf нас очень сковывает. Другой вариант - это это действительно создать свой контрол наследующий от ItemsControl. Там вы уже сможете добавить RoutedEvent, переопределить событие OnItemsChanged, и генерировать это событие при удалении.

Comment: @cvvvlad, то есть все что мне нужно - это подключить interactivity? Будем считать что подключил. А дальше что с ним делать? Я ведь конкретный вопрос задал.

Comment: Предложенный вариант от cvvvlad также может подойти для вас, я совсем забыл про Blend, так как использую VS2013 Express :) Но опыт работы с Blend у меня был, и с уверенностью могу сказать что это очень не плохая штука.

Comment: Да что такое то? Я задал вопрос "Как сделать?" а в ответ получаю "что использовать". Вы код предложите для моего вопроса, а я уже потом решу, как мне его создавать, руками или генерировать при помощи бленда

Answer (score 3):

Могу посоветовать использовать класс Storyboard - [см. пример на msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms742868(v=vs.110).aspx). Он позволит менять определенные значения плавно, например, высоту или ширину.
По поводу удаления: я бы посоветовал немного расширить View Model и добавить пару методов:

1. Свойство VisibilityState {get;}

В статье от Microsoft описывается реакция на наведение мыши. Аналогичным образом можно подписаться на выставление Hidden в Visibility и начать плавное уменьшение высоты. В конце надо поставить Visibility Collapsed. При установке этого свойства объект может уже удаляться из коллекции.

Что происходит с точки зрения модели:

1. Устанавливаем VisibilityState в Hidden
2. Ждем, пока элемент не станет Collapsed.
3. Удаляем элемент из коллекции

Что происходит с точки зрения пользователя:

1. Он совершает действие
2. Элемент исчезает, а все остальное аккуратненько сдвигается.